# NOT bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis

$C^{1}([0,1]; \mathbb{R}),C([0,1];\mathbb{R}) $ endowed with the norm $\|u\|=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|u(x)|$

\begin{eqnarray}
 Dom(T_{a})&=&C^{1}([0,1];\mathbb{R}),\, Ran(T_{a})=C([0,1];\mathbb{R})\\
T_{a}u(x)&=&u'(x)+a(x)u(x)\,; u\in D(T)   
\end{eqnarray}

Here $a \in C([0,1]; \mathbb{R})$.

I could prove $T_{a}$ is closed operator. But I think this linear operator $T_{a}$ is NOT bounded. In order to prove this, I have to find sequence of function $(u_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty},\, u_{n}\in C^{1}([0,1]; \mathbb{R})  $ such that , for example, $\|u_{n}\|\to 0$ and $ \| Tu_{n} \| \ \nrightarrow 0$. I am looking for  sequence of function like this. Please tell me if you find. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show that $D\colon u \mapsto u'$ is unbounded?

Comment: Yes. For example $u_{n}=\frac{x^{n}}{\sqrt[]{n}}$

Comment: And if you try that sequence for $T_a$, what do you get?

Comment: $T_{a}u_{n}=\sqrt[]{n}x^{n-1}+a(x) \frac{x^{n}}{\sqrt[]{n}}$.$|T_{a}u_{n}(x)|\geq |\sqrt[]{n}x^{n-1}|-|a(x) \frac{x^{n}}{ \sqrt[]{n}}| $

Comment: And can you see whether that is bounded?

Comment: Since $|T_{a}u_{n}(x)|\geq -\|a\| \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{n}} \geq -\|a\| $, $T_{a}u_{n}(x)$ is lower bounded.

Comment: I meant the norms. Is $\left(\lVert T_a u_n\rVert_\infty\right)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ bounded?

Comment: Well...I can't see...

Comment: I can't evaluate "$\sqrt[]{n}x^{n-1}$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that the operator $D\colon u \mapsto u'$ (defined on the same domain as $T_a$) is unbounded by looking at the sequence given by $u_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}x^n$.

Now there are several ways to see that $T_a$ is unbounded:

- We can use the same sequence, and note that $$\lVert T_a(u_n)\rVert \geqslant T_a(u_n)(1) = \sqrt{n}\cdot 1^{n-1} - a(1)\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}1^n \geqslant \sqrt{n} - \frac{\lVert a\rVert_\infty}{\sqrt{n}} \to \infty,$$
- or, we can more abstractly observe that the operator $M_a \colon u \mapsto a\cdot u$ is bounded (with norm $\lVert M_a\rVert = \lVert a\rVert_\infty$), and since $D = T_a - M_a$ is unbounded, $T_a$ cannot be bounded, for the difference of two bounded operators is again bounded.

(There are still other ways, but these two shall suffice here.)

Comment: Thanks. My worries have disappeared thanks to you.